# Tkinter Frame and griding

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am designing a front end using Tkinter but the .grid() option doesn't work as expected. I want to divide my screen to two section, LEFT and Right. All the buttons and labels on the left and the rest on the right.

```
     # Initialise frames
    self.frame_left = tk.Frame(root, bg = "pink", width = 100, height = 100).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'E')
    self.frame_right = tk.Frame(root, bg = "red", width = 100, height = 100).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'W')

    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)


    #labels
    self.Name_Label = tk.Label(self.frame_left, text = "Name", font = 12, fg = 'green').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    self.Phone_Label = tk.Label(self.frame_left, text = "Phone Number", font = 12, fg= 'green').grid(row = 1, column =2)
    self.University_label = tk.Label(self.frame_left, text = "University", font = 12, fg = 'green').grid(row = 1, column = 3)

    #Search boxex
    self.Name_box = tk.Entry(self.frame_left, width =  12, borderwidth = 2).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    self.Phone_box = tk.Entry(self.frame_left, width =  12, borderwidth = 2).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.Phone_box = tk.Entry(self.frame_left, width =  12, borderwidth = 2).grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    # Buttons
    self.Search_button = tk.Button(self.frame_left, text='Search', padx = 10, pady = 10, font = 12, fg = 'black').grid(row = 5, column = 1)

    #Screen
    #self.Screen = tk.Listbox(self.frame_right, width = 20, height = 20, font = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

It seems the labels and buttons are being placed on the root window not the frames that has been defined.

Appreciate your help.

Regards

Khisrow

Comment: You main problem is where you are placing `grid()`. When you need to define a variable like your Frame you cannot place grid at the end of the line. Because all geometry managers `grid()`, `pack()` and `place()` always return None so by adding `grid()` to then end of defining your widget the variable will actually be `None`. To fix this you can define your variable/widget on one line and on the next line apply your geometry manager to the variable. This is very importing for containers like Frames and Entry fields. For buttons and labels it only maters if you plan on editing them later.

Answer (score 0):

To divide your screen into 2 parts, you need to use the option `columnconfigure`:

```
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

This creates a grid on the `root` window with 2 columns in which your `self.frame_left` and `self.frame_right` can be placed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do as explained but it seems the labels and button are being placed on the root window not on the frames. I added my entire code for clarity.

Comment: @user3064089 the weights need to be `weight=1` in `columnconfigure`. I don't see a problem with the code. It should grid as chosen. Also, all the labels, search boxes and the button has `None` as `tk.Entry(...).grid(...)` return **None**

Answer (score 0):

When you store a `.grid()` item you are not storing the widget:

```
self.frame_left = tk.Frame(root, bg = "pink", width = 100, height = 100).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'E')
```

Stores the grid object to the variable, not the `Frame`.

This can be fixed by doing the creation and grid in two lines.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()

        #EXAMPLE OF DIFFERENCE
        self.frame_left = tk.Frame(root, bg = "pink", width = 100, height = 100).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'E')
        print(self.frame_left, "DIDN'T STORE THE FRAME")
        self.frame_left = tk.Frame(root, bg = "pink", width = 100, height = 100)
        self.frame_left.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'E')
        print(self.frame_left, "STORED THE FRAME")
        #EXAMPLE OF DIFFERENCE

         # Initialise frames
        self.frame_left = tk.Frame(root, bg = "pink", width = 100, height = 100)
        self.frame_left.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'E')
        self.frame_right = tk.Frame(root, bg = "red", width = 100, height = 100)
        self.frame_right.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'W')

        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)


        #labels
        self.Name_Label = tk.Label(self.frame_left, text = "Name", font = 12, fg = 'green').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.Phone_Label = tk.Label(self.frame_left, text = "Phone Number", font = 12, fg= 'green').grid(row = 1, column =2)
        self.University_label = tk.Label(self.frame_left, text = "University", font = 12, fg = 'green').grid(row = 1, column = 3)

        #Search boxex
        self.Name_box = tk.Entry(self.frame_left, width =  12, borderwidth = 2)
        self.Name_box.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.Phone_box = tk.Entry(self.frame_left, width =  12, borderwidth = 2)
        self.Phone_box.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        self.Phone_box = tk.Entry(self.frame_left, width =  12, borderwidth = 2)
        self.Phone_box.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

        # Buttons
        self.Search_button = tk.Button(self.frame_left, text='Search', padx = 10, pady = 10, font = 12, fg = 'black').grid(row = 5, column = 1)

        #Screen
        #self.Screen = tk.Listbox(self.frame_right, width = 20, height = 20, font = 1).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

Test()
```

[image]

EDIT: added a listbox with scrollbar

```
# Screen
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame_right)
scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nsw')
self.Screen = tk.Listbox(self.frame_right, width = 20, height = 5, font = 1)
self.Screen.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
self.Screen.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=self.Screen.yview)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I followed the steps and yes, it did help but as soon as I tried to add a Listbox on the red frame, the whole shape changed. I thought each frame should be independent of each other?

Comment: It scaled root to the size of the `Listbox`, since they share the same root window, you probably want a smaller listbox with a scrollbar, but that is an entirely different question. http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm